# Getting list from collection in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot App and MongoDB for database.

In database I have collection `packageholiday`, and inside it some elements, this is JSON:

```
    [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62bf6a6121d6c6a226d6b418"
  },
  "title": "Cambodia",
  "description": "Cambodia, a country located in Southeast Asia, is bordered by the Lao People's Democratic Republic to the northeast, Thailand to the northwest, Vietnam to the east, and the Gulf of Thailand to the southwest. Cambodia gained its independence in 1953 and is a member of the Association of South-East Asia Nations (ASEAN). Cambodia has a multiparty democracy under a constitutional monarchy, with Phnom Penh as the capital. Cambodia’s official language is Khmer, and the currency is the riel (KHR).",
  "whatToDo": "Start off by exploring the temples of Angkor Wat while you base yourself in the town of Siem Reap. If you’re into adventuring and going at it alone, rent a bike and get your exercise sweating your way through these 12th century ruins. Alternatively, sign up with one of the hostel tours to get a feel for the temples and meet some other wannabe Indiana Jones travellers along the way. From Siem Reap, don’t miss out on Cambodia’s capital Phnom Penh to learn about the country’s difficult history in the 1970s through a visit its jarring museums, S21 and the Killing Fields. There are plenty of great cafes and restaurants in the city that were made for solo travellers just like you! Then get your water fix by heading down to the islands off of Sihanoukville for some serious beach time and partying, or to the riverside haven of Kampot for kayaking and great coffee. ",
  "packageHolidayType": [
    "indepedentTours"
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62bf6b5521d6c6a226d6b41b"
  },
  "title": "Myanmar",
  "description": "The Republic of the Union of Myanmar (or more commonly known as Myanmar) has an area of 676,578 square kilometres, making it the second largest country in Southeast Asia. It shares borders with Bangladesh, China, India, Laos, and Thailand. Naypyidaw is the capital of Myanmar, and Yangon, as the former capital, is the country’s most important commercial centre.",
  "whatToDo": "Head to the most famous place in Myanmar, Bagan, where you can rent out an e-bike (solo or with a group from your hostel) to explore over 2,000 temples and pagodas. You can also hop in some shared transport to visit the nearby Mount Popa, a monastery perched on top of an extinct volcano with 777 stairs to climb and maybe even more monkeys to get past. From Bagan you can head to Hsipaw or Kalaw that act as starting points for multi-day treks to see Myanmar’s countryside and rest your head in homestays along the way. Treks are also a great way to meet new travel friends. And if you’re craving a bit of reflective solo time? You can visit places like the enchanting Shwedagon Pagoda in Yangon or Mandalay’s U Bein Bridge where flocks of people congregate every sunrise and sunset. Both are magical places to explore solo, although you’re likely to get invited to join a local family for a snack at both.",
  "packageHolidayType": [
    "indepedentTours"
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62bf6d0d21d6c6a226d6b41d"
  },
  "title": "Classical Spain",
  "description": "Experience Andalucía’s magical fusion of Spanish and Moorish cultures as you discover Seville’s vibrant streets and conquistador heritage, Granada’s wondrous Alhambra and the dazzling Mezquita mosque in Córdoba – and much more. Andalucía is simply one of the most beautiful corners of Europe yet for many it remains relatively undiscovered. It’s a land where the excesses of the modern era seem not to have taken root and where travellers are genuinely welcomed. The food is a delight, with the area noted for its seafood and its famous drink, the fortified wine from Jerez we call sherry. Try a glass of fino, a very dry yet refreshing sherry, while nibbling tapas, that great Spanish titbit invention. The people are charming – always ready to help, with a friendly attitude towards their fellow man and a love of life so typical of Mediterranean people. So, for an inspirational blend of timeless countryside, iconic monuments, romantic and vivacious cities, fragrant flowers and orange blossom, wonderful art and superb cuisine, all set in a region that welcomes visitors as honoured guests, welcome to Andalucía.",
  "packageHolidayType": [
    "escortedTours"
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62bf6e08d4a37b95af66f59f"
  },
  "title": "Japan",
  "description": "Japan - an ancient culture of emperors, fierce shoguns, samurais and brutal martial arts. Yet it’s also a place of gentle geishas, colourful kimonos, exquisite garden design and Zen Buddhism. How did a country so deeply rooted in such diverse heritage become one of the most modern and advanced economies on the planet? Pondering such questions is what makes a trip to Japan so incredibly rewarding. Having travelled there once, you’ll feel almost hypnotically drawn back to this truly enigmatic country.\n\nJapan’s roots lie in an ancient feudal culture, with many customs from these times still pervading modern society. The Portuguese and Jesuit missionaries arrived in the 16th century and by all accounts, they were initially treated well, mainly because the Japanese were impressed with their new technology – firearms. Despite trading together successfully for nearly a century, Christianity and western ideas were deemed to be undermining the social order and the Portuguese were expelled. All contact with outsiders was banned for over 200 years. The only country on earth to have been so completely isolated from all external influences, Japanese art and culture developed in its own unique way, until pressure from the US finally broke down the barriers in the 1850’s.",
  "packageHolidayType": [
    "escortedTours"
  ]
}]
```

What is my goal:

As you can see I have Array like this in collection:

```
 "packageHolidayType": [
    "indepedentTours" //type
  ]



    "packageHolidayType": [
    "escortedTours" //type
  ]
```

So my problem is actually creating API that will return element from collection with specified `packageHolidayType`.

For example.

API for `packageHolidayType` > `escortedTours`

```
@GetMapping("/getEscortedTours")
....
How to filter here just that type
```

And for example same for

API for `packageHolidayType` > `indepedentTours`

```
@GetMapping("/getIndepedentTours")
....
How to filter here just that type
```

On which way I can achieve this? Is this even possible on that way?

Answer (score 0):

Use **In** Query with spring data

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

The following implementation works for the use case described above:

```
@Repository
public interface PackageHolidayRepository extends MongoRepository<PackageHoliday, String> {
     List<PackageHoliday> findByPackageHolidayTypeIn(List<String> packageHolidayTypes);
}
```

Or You can use Query with Contains:

```
 @Query("{ packageHolidayType: { $all: ?0 } }")
 List<PackageHoliday> findByackageHolidayType(String packageHolidayType);
```

Comment: I'm okay with that, but I didn't set which type I want? I need controller that will show me element just for `escortedType` and another controller that will show me element just for `indepedentTours`